# sort values a data frame with duplicates values

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, sorting, duplicates

I have a dataframe with a format like this:

```
d = {'col1': ['PC', 'PO', 'PC', 'XY', 'XY', 'AB', 'AB', 'PC', 'PO'], 'col2': 
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


df.sort_values(by = 'col1')
```

This gives me the result like this:

[image]

I want to sort the values based on col1 values with desired order, keep the duplicates. The result I expect would be like this:

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an order beforehand and then sort values as below.

```py
order = ['PO','XY','AB','PC']
df['col1'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['col1'], ordered=True, categories=order)

df = df.sort_values(by = 'col1')
df


    col1    col2
1   PO      2
8   PO      9
3   XY      4
4   XY      5
5   AB      6
6   AB      7
0   PC      1
2   PC      3
7   PC      8
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I asked my question in the wrong way!  This df was just an example. My data frame is a large one and if I use df.sort_values(by = 'column name'), the values will be sorted based on alphabets, but I don't want this. I want to sort them as a special order :)

Comment: What do you mean by special order? Can you include sample data of your dataframe so that anyone can help?

Comment: I edited my question. I hope I could be clear this time.

Comment: It works well for the example. Although, surprisingly for the original df, it turns all the values of the selected column into NaN! My df contains 136252 rows × 10 columns. Can you guess what could be the problem? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not sure but can you check if you are giving the order and column name correctly.